# Filtering branches with BitBucket REST API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I'm new to the BitBucket REST API and I'm having an issue I hope that someone can help me with.

I'm attempting to get information about a branch, 'TEST-BRANCH'.  After reading this page:  https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/version-2-423626329.html, here is my curl command:

curl --user {user}:{password} https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{user}/{slug}/refs/branches?q=name+%7E+%22TEST-BRANCH%2F%22

However, the response that I receive from making this curl request is as follows:

{"pagelen": 10, "values": [], "page": 1, "size": 0}

When I run the curl command without the filters:
curl --user {user}:{password} https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{user}/{slug}/refs/branches

I get a massive list of all my branches and I can clearly see the TEST-BRANCH there with "type": "branch", "name": "TEST-BRANCH"

What have I missed here?

Thanks,
axl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks the query contains an extra `%2F` character - the string decodes to `"TEST-BRANCH/"`. Remove that `%2F` and you should be good to go.