# bitbucket API Rest - Getting branches from a repository

Tags: bitbucket-api

I am looking for the list of endpoints available for bitbucket API regarding get the branches from a repository and a specific branch.

I was expecting to see something like:

```
GET /2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/branches/

GET /2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/branches/{branch}
```

So I can get the commits from a specific branch.

I know [I can get commits](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-commits/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-commits-get) but with this endpoint, its scope is under repository perspective.

Do you know if there are endpoints to work with branches and recursively into its hierarchy?
I looked over the [documentation for API 2.0](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/intro/) but I did not see what I was looking for so that is why I am posting this question here.

In addition, I see some time ago that was not possible according to [this answer](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Bitbucket-Server-API-to-get-information-of-all-the-branches-in-a/qaq-p/958227), but it belongs to the version 1.0 of the API. Is it still true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When hitting [this endpoint](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-repositories/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-get):

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<workspace>/<repository-name>`
# GET /2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}
```

You get as a result a JSON document. In the `links` attribute you got a key called `branches`. It is something like this:

```
{
    "scm": "git",
    "has_wiki": false,
    "links": {
        "watchers": {
            "href": "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/watchers"
        },
        "branches": {
            "href": "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/refs/branches"
        },
     ....
```

So you can hit the endpoint and get the branches:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/refs/branches
# GET /2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/refs/branches
```

And get a specific branch with

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/refs/branches/<branch-name>
# GET /2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/refs/branches/<branch-name>
```

Comment: How to find all branches starting with a specific key word? My goal is to get all the release branches starting with a certain version. Say get all release  branches of version 2 like release-2.0, release-2.0.1, rrelease-2.1 etc so I am basically I am trying to filter branches with name starting "release-2*" tags in my branch name.  This is what I tried -> https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<workspace>/<repo-slug>/refs/branches?search=release-21.5*&branchtype=release  but not getting what I wanted . Thanks

Comment: Thanks - I fixed it by adding the query as provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36380957/filtering-branches-with-bitbucket-rest-api?rq=1
branches?q=name+%7E+%22release-21.5%22